# Firebase authentication persistence in node.js server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), the default persistence for node.js backend is none. I want to change it to either SESSION or LOCAL because my node.js backend stops working because of authentication timeout. However, I get this error when I try to change it to either one:

```
The current environment does not support the specified persistence type
```

How can I make the Firebase Login made in a node.js server stay forever?

Comment: The documentation suggests that "forever" is not possible.  Of your options for [Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#.Persistence), there is no option for "forever".

Comment: I just added the "onAuthStateChanged" method to detect if the session ends, and login back when it does. I will see if it helps achieve this

Comment: just curious: are you authenticating a server, or end users? The link you shared relates to the JS/Web SDK, not the Admin(server) SDK.

Comment: @RonRoyston There is a node client SDK as well.

Comment: @DougStevenson ...interesting. When I click on [node sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) from the [Firebase Libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/) page it takes me to the "Admin SDK". ...just curious, node is a server right? Wouldn't a node server use a private key for authentication?

Comment: If you want to use session cookies (equivalent of LOCAL persistence on server side node.js), consider looking into: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: I am not using admin SDK. I am simply logging in as a user on the node.js server